# Python reading text file every second line skipped

Tags: python, shell, file, text-files

I am processing a shell script in Python. My first step is to comb through the file and save only the important lines in a list (of strings). However, I have isolated a problem where every second line is ignored. Why is the second, fourth, etc. line skipped in the following code?

```
f = open("sample_failing_file.txt", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
readfile = f.read()
filelines = readfile.split("\n")

def remove_irrelevant_lines(filecontent: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    for line in filecontent:
        if drop_line_appropriate(line):
            filecontent.remove(line)
    return filecontent

def drop_line_appropriate(line: str) -> bool:
    if line.startswith("#"):
        return True
    # some more conditions, omitted here
    return False

filelines = remove_irrelevant_lines(filelines)
f.close()
```

When I run this code, I can see **filecontent** is complete. However, when I look at **line**, I can see e.g. **some line 3** is never read. Here is a simplified version of the shell script, on which my Python script fails (sample_failing_file.txt)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# some line 1
#
# some line 2
# some line 3
```

Comment: You should not [remove while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406). Use a list comprehension instead: `return [line for line in filecontent if not drop_line_appropriate(line)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't try to remove elements from a list while iterating over it.  Additionally, when removing lines, don't want to use `list.remove()`, since that causes it to search for the line, which will make it run vastly slower than it should.

The following should fix your problem and also run vastly faster:

```
def remove_irrelevant_lines(filecontent: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [line for line in filecontent if not drop_line_appropriate(line)]
```

This creates and returns a new list, filtering out the lines indicated by `drop_line_appropriate`.